# socket connection recvfrom no response C++

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, recvfrom

I am trying to get data from UDP broadcast, but no response from `recvfrom` function. Connection, binding, everything looks fine.

Can there be a problem with the broadcast?

Is there anyway I can check the exact error?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//#include <ServerSocket.h>
#include <cstring>      
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <netdb.h>      
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    enter code here
    int status;
    int socketfd;
    int enableMulticast = 1;         // Argument for set socket 

    struct addrinfo host_info;       // The struct that getaddrinfo() fills up with data.
    struct addrinfo *host_info_list; // Pointer to the to the linked list of host_info's.
    struct sockaddr_in socketAddr;
    unsigned char incomming_data_buffer[IN_LEN];
    socklen_t socklen;
    #ifndef IN_LEN    
    #define IN_LEN 4096
    #endif  

    memset(&host_info, 0, sizeof host_info);
    memset(&socketAddr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

    cout << "Setting up the structs..."  << endl;

    host_info.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;     // IP version not specified. Can be both.
    host_info.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM; // Use SOCK_STREAM for TCP or SOCK_DGRAM for UDP.
    host_info.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_UDP; // The protocol type for UDP. If left as zero, it will return all types


    status = getaddrinfo("UDP IP Address","Port", &host_info, &host_info_list);

    socketfd = socket(host_info_list->ai_family, host_info_list->ai_socktype,
                      host_info_list->ai_protocol);
    if (socketfd == -1)  cout << "socket error " ;
    else cout << "socket created successfully " ;

    status = setsockopt(socketfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &enableMulticast, sizeof(enableMulticast));

    socketAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    socketAddr.sin_port = htons(INT_PORT);
    socketAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    status = bind(socketfd, (struct sockaddr *)&socketAddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));    

    status = connect(socketfd, host_info_list->ai_addr, host_info_list->ai_addrlen);
    if (status < 0)  cout << "connect error" <<endl ;

    cout << "Waiting to receive data..."  << endl;
    socklen = sizeof(struct socketAddr);

    while(1){
        status = recvfrom(socketfd, incomming_data_buffer, IN_LEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&socketAddr, &socklen);

        if(status >= 0) {
            cout << "data received" ;
            freeaddrinfo(host_info_list);
            close(socketfd);

            exit(0);
         }
    }     
}
```

Comment: I never used `connect()` to receive broadcast packets. What is the rational for `connect()`?

Comment: @harper It's documented. See the *man* page.

Comment: Are you able to see the packets arriving in Wireshark?

Comment: "Wireshark" what is that?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(status = 0)
```

This can never be true. (1) it's a typo for `status == 0`; (2) it should be `status >= 0`, i.e.`status` is the length of the datagram received.

Comment: I think you can ignore that. The problem is with recvfrom function. For some reason it is getting hanged.

Comment: The main problem is the program is not moving forward after recvfrom function.